# 2 values from 1 input, PHP MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post, input

I'm building a validator script for barcode ticketing system. Which needs to check the barcode number against database. The thing is the first 7 numbers of the barcode is customer id and the last 4 numbers are the seat id.

For example:

```
12345671234
^^^^^^^--Customer ID
       ^^^^-- Seat ID
```

As I'll scan the barcode using a barcode scanner and it will 
write whole barcode on a single input box I need to seperate these 2 values in that 
1 input in order to get proper data from database.

Its now like:

```
<form action="validator.php" method="post">
Customer ID: <input id="uuid" name="uuid" maxlength="7"><br>
Seat:       <input id="hash" name="hash" maxlength="4">
```

Needs to be like:

```
Barcode: <input id="barcode" name="barcode" maxlength="11"><input  type="submit">

<input  type="submit">
</form>
```

And the PHP Side

```
<?php

$uuid = $_POST['uuid'];
$hash = $_POST['hash'];




    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","321","db_name");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM seat_booking_bookings
    WHERE uuid ='$uuid'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo $row['customer_name'] . " " . $row['customer_phone'];
      echo "<br>";
      }

      $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM seat_booking_bookings_seats
    WHERE hash ='$hash'");

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
       echo "Seat:";
      echo $row['seat_id'] . " " . $row['price'];

      }
    ?>
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What is your question? also, how is $hash calculated?

Comment: Your code is still vulnerable to SQL injection. Learn about prepared statements.

Comment: @cernunnos obviously the question is How?

Comment: I just want to know how can I seperate the input into 2 values and post to the php file.

Comment: Using [substring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: Is the customer ALWAYS 7 characters and is the seat ALWAYS 4 characters? (or can it be more or less?)

Comment: People who vote to close, please bear in mind that this is a new user of SO and it is a real question with code and everything

Comment: He simply needs to reword the question imho, @mplungjan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
$uuid = substr($_POST['barcode'], 0,7);
$hash = substr($_POST['barcode'], 7,4);
```

Refer this. [**PHP Substring**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$uuid = substr($_POST['barcode'], 0, 7);  
$hash = substr($_POST['barcode'], 7, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an AND statement in your query.  You're trying to validate based on two values, right?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM seat_booking_bookings 
WHERE uuid ='{$uuid}' AND hash ='{$hash}'");
```

However, to prevent sql injection you should escape your values first. So this would be better:

```
$uuid = mysql_real_escape_string($uuid);
$hash = mysql_real_escape_string($hash);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM seat_booking_bookings 
WHERE uuid ='{$uuid}' AND hash ='{$hash}'");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$uuid = substr($_POST['barcode'],0,7);
$hash = substr($_POST['barcode'],7,4);
```

i think this is what you are looking for...

Comment: Please check the syntax before post the answer

Comment: The string comes first... and then start, and then length.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for but it needs to be fixed.